# Enter data in dictionary from two arrays

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have the following two arrays which I want to merge in a dictionary:

```
# Input:
wrd = ['i', 'am', 'am', 'the', 'boss', 'the', 'tiger', 'eats', 'rice', 'eats', 'grass']
cnt = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# Output: 
{
    'i': [0],
    'am': [1,2],
    'the': [3,5],
    'boss': [4],
    'tiger': [6],
    'eats': [7,9],
    'rice': [8],
    'grass': [10]
}
```

I have tried the following code, but I think my idea is leading me wrong way:

```
    dict={}
    j=0
    for i in wrd:
        if i in dict:
           dict[i].insert(cnt[j])
        else:
           dict[i].append(cnt[j])
           j+=1

    v=dict.values()
    k=dict.keys()
    for k,v in dict.items():
         print k,v
```

As I am a newbie in python, I acknowledge my lack of knowledge here.

Comment: What issue do you have in your code? Does it give any error? Does it give wrong output?

Comment: @RohitJain: Error: dict[i].append(cnt[j])....KeyError: 'i'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the right tool for the job (here, `defaultdict`, as in Sukrit Kalra's answer) is always the best solution. But it's also useful to understand what's wrong with your attempt.

```
if i in dict:
   dict[i].insert(cnt[j])
else:
   dict[i].append(cnt[j])
   j+=1
```

If `i` is already in the `dict`, that's fine: `dict[i]` is a list, and you're going to call `insert` on it. That's not going to work, but only because `insert` requires two parameters—the index to insert the object, as well as the object to insert. Just change that to `append(cnt[j])`, or `insert(0, cnt[j])`, or whatever is appropriate.

But if `i` is *not* already in the `dict`, you're trying to `append` to something that doesn't exist. That obviously won't work. You have to create a `list` and put it in `dict[i]` before you can do anything to `dict[i]`. So, you can just change that line to:

```
    dict[i] = [cnt[j]]
```

… and that will solve it.

And once you understand that, you can hopefully understand why Sukrit Kalra's answer is so cool: a `defaultdict` is just a `dict` that *automatically* creates a default value for any keys that aren't present. So, you can just write `dict[i].append(cnt[j])` and it will work whether `dict[i]` already existed or not.

---

As a side note, naming a dict `dict` is a bad idea, because that hides the builtin class and constructor of the same name.

More generally, it always helps to use better names. The keystrokes you save with your cryptic abbreviations and one-letter names will be more than canceled out by the keystrokes you waste debugging your code and explaining it to people who you need to ask for help. Call the input something like `words` and `counts`, the outer loop variable `word`, the `j` counter something like `count_index`, etc.

Meanwhile: `cnt` is almost completely useless. For any number up to 10, `cnt[j]` is just `j`, and for any number above 10, it's an `IndexError`. Why not just use `j`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here. See the snippet

```
>>> wrd=['i','am','am','the','boss','the','tiger','eats','rice','eats','grass']
>>> cnt=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, val in zip(wrd, cnt): # Preferably for val, key in enumerate(wrd):
        a[key].append(val)


>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'grass': [10], 'i': [0], 'am': [1, 2], 'eats': [7, 9], 'boss': [4], 'tiger': [6], 'the': [3, 5], 'rice': [8]})
>>> a['am']
[1, 2]
>>> a['the']
[3, 5]
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your simple and straight solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a counter list. Enumerate will do it for you:

```
list(enumerate(['i','am','am','the','boss','the','tiger','eats','rice','eats','grass']))
#=> [(0, 'i'), (1, 'am'), (2, 'am'), (3, 'the'), (4, 'boss'), (5, 'the'), (6, 'tiger'), (7, 'eats'), (8, 'rice'), (9, 'eats'), (10, 'grass')]
```

Now, you can collect those up with a defaultdict:

```
collect = defaultdict(list)
for idx, wrd in enumerate(['i','am','am','the','boss','the','tiger','eats','rice','eats','grass']):
    collect[wrd].append(idx)
```

But, the real question is why you need this. What are you going to do with these indices back into the original list?